# Multiple rows returned by a subquery used as an expression 

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which runs perfectly well on both Oracle and SQL Server 2008 however it doesn't seem to run on PostgreSQL. The query is intended to return a count of records that match the given criteria. Can someone explain the reason for this and also offer a solution to how this query can be modified to allow it to produce the expected result.

Query:

```
select count(*) 
from tma_notices 
where TNOT_NOTICE_TYPE ='0400' 
and TNOT_NOTICE_STATUS = 'OK' 
and tnot_notice_id >= 
    (
        select NOTICE_NUM_AT_MIDNIGHT 
        from RWOL_COUNTER_QUERY_TYPE 
        where QUERY_TYPE = 'START_NOTICES_TODAY' 
        and USER_NAME = 'PUBLIC'
    )
```

UPDATE: This error was caused by unforeseen duplicate records in the PostgreSQL database. Where the duplicates came from needs to be investigated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty clear that the subquery could return a set of rows and the condition `tnot_notice_id >=` isn't valid if compared with a set of rows and not with only a single value.

Are you sure that exist a unique record that satisfy your where conditions?

If you want to avoid that behaviour, I suggest you to use `tnot_notice_id >= ALL ( subquery )`

Comment: Bizarrely I have just checked and the table that this code references actually has duplicated records which has caused this issue. This must have happened during cloning the database. I will have to investigate further but thanks for your answer.

Comment: @CSharpened: I would assume that at least with Oracle the original query would have failed as well if the sub-query returned more than one row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : i totally agree

Comment: Yes the issue was caused by duplicated rows in the database. To get round this temporarily until the database has been recreated I have added a distinct keyword it. Far from ideal but allows me to continue with the project until that has been done.

Comment: @CSharpened: thank you for the info. All is good for increase experience